# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) when doing Djisktras algorithm?

Tags: python

I am getting the error when running the following code, its supposed to be a djikstras algorithm running over certain nodes and edges, with weights. But when trying to run I get an error.

```
nodes = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'] 
edges = {('0', '1'): 1, ('0', '4'): 1, ('0', '5'): 1, ('1', '2'): 0, ('2', '3'): 0, ('4', '3'): 0, ('5', '6'): 0, ('6', '7'):0, ('7', '3'): 0}

def dijkstra(nodes, edges, source_index=0):
    path_lenghts = {v: float('inf') for v in nodes}
    path_lenghts[source_index] = 0

    adjacent_nodes = {v: {} for v in nodes}
    for (u, v), w_uv in edges.items():
        adjacent_nodes[u][v] = w_uv
        adjacent_nodes[v][u] = w_uv
    
    temporary_nodes = [v for v in nodes]
    while len(temporary_nodes) > 0:
        upper_bounds = {v: path_lenghts[v] for v in temporary_nodes}
        u = min(upper_bounds, key = upper_bounds.get)
        temporary_nodes.remove(u)

        for v, w_uv in adjacent_nodes[u].items():
            path_lenghts[v] = min(path_lenghts[v], path_lenghts[u] + w_uv)
    
    return path_lenghts

shortest_path_lenghts, shortest_paths = dijkstra(nodes, edges)

print(shortest_path_lenghts)

print(shortest_paths)
```

The error itself seems to be in the final part of the code

```
---> 30 shortest_path_lenghts, shortest_paths = dijkstra(nodes, edges)
     32 print(shortest_path_lenghts)
     34 print(shortest_paths)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am a bit confused over what values were exptected to be 2?

Comment: You're trying to assign the return value of the function to two variables. So the function needs to return some iterable with two values. But it really returns a dict with who knows how many values.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but your code says

```
shortest_path_lenghts, shortest_paths = dijkstra(nodes, edges)
```

which means that it expect the function dijkstra to return two variables (shortest_path_lengths and shortest_paths).

The function itself seems to only return a single variable `return path_lenghts`